# Binding fires on unloaded view/view-model when creating a new view

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

If I bind a RadioButton to a view-model property using a type converter, every time I create a view, the setter on the previous ViewModel gets called, even though the view is Unloaded and should not exist anymore. Here is the minimum code to reproduce the issue:

1) Define an enum type:

```
enum EnumType {
   Value1,
   Value2,
}
```

2) Define a convereter:

```
public class EnumTypeToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) {
      return true;
   }
   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) {
      return EnumType.Value1; 
   }
}
```

3) Define a view-model:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private EnumType value;
     public ViewModel() {
         Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ViewModel ({0})::ctor", this.GetHashCode()));
    }
    public EnumType Value {
        get {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ViewModel ({0})::Value::get", this.GetHashCode()));
            return this.value;
        }
        set {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ViewModel ({0})::Value::set", this.GetHashCode()));
            if (this.value != value) {
                this.value = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null) {
            var ea = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name);
            this.PropertyChanged(this, ea);
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

4) Define a UserControl (View.xaml)

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="BindingIssue.View"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:BindingIssue"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    x:Name="root">

   <UserControl.DataContext>
       <local:ViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
   </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
       <ScrollViewer>       
           <StackPanel>
              <RadioButton x:Name="rdo1"
                           Content="Value1"
                           IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource EnumTypeToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Value1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                <Button x:Name="btnClose"
                        Click="btnClose_Click"
                        Content="Close"/>
           </StackPanel>
       </ScrollViewer>
   </Grid>
```

5) Add code behind of the View:

```
public View() {
     Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("View ({0})::ctor", this.GetHashCode()));
     this.InitializeComponent();
     this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
     this.Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
}
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (this.Parent is Popup) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Closing the popup...");
        ((Popup)this.Parent).IsOpen = false;
    }
}
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("View ({0})::Loaded", this.GetHashCode()));
  }
private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("View ({0})::Unloaded", this.GetHashCode()));
}
```

6) MainPage (XAML)

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
         x:Name="Grid">
    <Button x:Name="btnNewView"
              Click="btnNewView_Click"
              Content="New View"
              Margin="4"/>
</Grid>
```

7) Add the event handler to the MainPage

```
private void btnNewView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Opening a new popup...");
    View view = new View();
    view.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    view.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

    Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.Child = view;
    popup.HorizontalOffset = 300;
    popup.VerticalOffset = 300;
    popup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Opening and closing popups multiple times results the following output (Please keep track of hash codes):

> Opening a new popup...
>
> View (46418718)::ctor
>
> ViewModel (59312528)::ctor
>
> ViewModel (59312528)::Value::get
>
> View (46418718)::Loaded
>
> Closing the popup...
>
> **View (46418718)::Unloaded**
>
> Opening a new popup...
>
> View (58892413)::ctor
>
> ViewModel (61646925)::ctor
>
> ViewModel (61646925)::Value::get
>
> **ViewModel (59312528)::Value::set**
>
> View (58892413)::Loaded
>
> Closing the popup...
>
> View (58892413)::Unloaded

Which means the setter for the ViewModel that is created in the Unloaded view model is being called that is a little bit strange. This behavior is the same for both x:Bind and Binding.

I would like to know if there is an explanation on this behavior.

**To Clarify more:**
A brand new pair of view/view-model instances are created each time but when the new view is being loaded, the setter on the previous instance of view-model is being called. The previous instance of the view is unloaded and should not even exist at that point. (Think of a popup that is being closed each time, and there is not event a reference the old view/view-model.)

Answer (score 0):

> Which means the setter for the ViewModel that is created in the Unloaded view 
>   model is being called that is a little bit strange

Firstly, the `setter` is not called when the view unloaded, it is called when loading the view. You can add the [Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loading.aspx) event handle to verify this. Adding loading event code to the code behind of `view` control as follows:

```
  this.Loading += View_Loading;       
  private void View_Loading(FrameworkElement sender, object args)
  {
      Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("View ({0})::Loading", this.GetHashCode()));
  }
```

And the output now will be:

```
Closing the popup...
View (22452836)::Unloaded
Opening a new popup...
View (58892413)::ctor
ViewModel (61646925)::ctor
View (58892413)::Loading
ViewModel (61646925)::Value::get
ViewModel (19246503)::Value::set
View (58892413)::Loaded
```

Secondly, we need to look into why `setter` is called in this scenario.
One is because you set the binding mode to `TwoWay`. If you remove this property as follows you will not see the `setter` called since the `ViewModel` doesn't need to know the changes in the `view`.

```
<RadioButton x:Name="rdo1"  Content="Value1"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource EnumTypeToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Value1,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

More details about binding mode please reference [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br209822). Another reason may be the specific for [`RadioButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.radiobutton.aspx) control. A `RadioButton` can be cleared by clicking another RadioButton in the same group, but it cannot be cleared by clicking it again. So when set `IsChecked` property to true, we thought the property value of the group is updated. This will trigger the `TwoWay` binding. In your scenrio, you can test this by setting the default value of `IsChecked` to false as follows, and you will find the `setter` is not called until you select the `rdo1` on the UI. Or you can use another control `CheckBox` for testing which will also not call the `setter` until `IsChecked` value updated.

```
public class EnumTypeToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
       return EnumType.Value1;       
    }
}
```

> The behavior is NOT the same if ScrollViewer gets removed from the View
>   The behavior is NOT the same for lets say a Boolean property

For these two scenarios, I also tested on my side. The result is the same with the outputs above. Since I don't know how you bind the `Boolean` property, as I mentioned, whether `setter` is called depend on what the binding mode is and whether you set or update the property. My testing code about binding `Boolean` is as follows which have same outputs.

View.xaml

```
<RadioButton x:Name="rdo2"
           Content="BoolValue"
           IsChecked="{Binding Path=BoolValue, Converter={StaticResource EnumTypeToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=Value1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Converter:

```
public class EnumTypeToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        //return EnumType.Value1;     
        return true;  
    }
}
```

ViewModel;

```
   private bool boolvalue;
   public bool BoolValue
   {
       get
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ViewModel ({0})::boolvalue::get", this.GetHashCode()));
           return this.boolvalue;
       }
       set
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("ViewModel ({0})::boolvalue::set", this.GetHashCode()));
           if (this.boolvalue != value)
           {
               this.boolvalue = value;
               this.OnPropertyChanged();
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but I think you missed the whole point of the question: Why the setter is being called on the "old" view model when a new instance of the view (and new view-model) is loaded? Please note that I do not reload the old view, I create a "new" pair of view and view-model  each time and the old one should be out of scope (or GC'ed) at that point. And I didn't said the setter is being called when the view is Unloaded. I said the setter is being called on the unloaded view/view model. That view-model should be dead at that point.

Comment: You are right about the scroll viewer thing, it happens without the scroll viewer as well. I updated the question but the main point of the question remained unanswered.